# One fruit to rule them all

Tags: word, wordplay

As I went to visit one of my friends, he asked me to follow him in his living room. In there was a table, with 6 fruits lined up on it: a peach, a banana, an apple, a tamarillo, an honeydew and a feijoa.

My friend then told me:

> If you are able to find the name of the fruit that I hid with these 6, I will let you taste some.

What may I be lucky enough to eat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> Papaya

Found by:

> Taking the first letter from the first fruit (**p**each), second from second (b**a**nana), etc.

Comment: Well, that was fast. Good job, I will enjoy some papaya then!

Comment: To be honest, I was quite surprised I found it so quickly... I guess the "hid with these" put me on the right track right away. I first just checked the first ones, but that didn't work out, so then I tried this method.